# passing two same values to an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an Activiy which show the route between two geopoints. and it take that two geopoints.

this actvity looks like

```
 final double fromLat = location.getLatitude();  // user location
 final double fromLon = location.getLongitude();

 final double toLat=this.getIntent().getDoubleExtra("tolat", 0.0);
 final double toLon=this.getIntent().getDoubleExtra("tolng",0.0);
    Log.v(tag, "flat"+fromLat+"flon"+fromLon+"toLat"+toLat+"tolon"+toLon);
          new Thread() {
               @Override
                  public void run() {
                     String url = RoadProvider.getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
                            InputStream is = getConnection(url);
                            mRoad = RoadProvider.getRoute(is);
                            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
            }.start();
    }
```

And two more activities in first it load the list of the neaby place and in second we can search for any city and it also show the list of nearby place in that city.

If user click on on an item in any list of both activities i want to show the route. it means i want to pass lat and lng (geopoints) from both activity.

In above code toLat and toLng will remain same but fromLat and fromLng will change according to from which ListActivity user clicked.

How can i pass the value from my citysearch activity so that fromLat and fromLng will change according to particular activity.

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the values with intent using putextra method of intent.
and get the values using the getExtra method.

```
// Put values with intent. 
Intent intent_name = new Intent(nearby_place.this,geopoint.class);
intent_name.putExtra("longitude", "72");
intent_name.putExtra("latitude", "22");
startActivity(intent_name);

// Put values with intent. 
Intent intent_name = new Intent(city_search.this,geopoint.class);
intent_name.putExtra("longitude", "72");
intent_name.putExtra("latitude", "22");
startActivity(intent_name);

//Get values which comes with intent
// You can get the values of longitude & latitude in geopoint class as below method
int longitude = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("longitude");
int latitude = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("latitude");
```

Comment: Ya i know but in my code writen above works for only user current location but if i'll pass the lat and lng from seacrhCity activity. then how the fromLat and fromLng will change accordingly.All i want to say is i can only use one fromLat and fromLng and pass it to the function but i have two.

Comment: You get the lat & long values in geopoint activity using getExtra method. when you come at geopoint activity after currentlocation activity you get the lat & long from currentlocation activity and if you come at geopoint activity after citysearch activity you get the lat & long from citysearch activity